# Adding a css class to mapped elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code line on my application `users.skills.map {|m| m.name}` which is returning the user's skills.

I would like this skills to be styled with some css styles and I was trying to figure out on how I can add a style to each one of the skills. Any clue?

Comment: The output is something like that: <p>RubyJavaAngularJS</p> | If I add a class to this it will be applied to the whole <p>. If I store them into an array how can I add the class then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question, but you could do it like this:

```
users.skills.map {|m| "<p class='your_css_class'>#{m.name}</p>"}
```

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HAML:

```
-users.skills.each do |s|
  .class
    =s.name
```

Comment: Thanks Chloe. I am using erb.